# PowerBI Dax Query Values from Two Tables

Tags: rest, powerbi, dax

I have a PowerBI Rest API application which needs to get data from two tables in a dataset. I am trying to make it work per this solution: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/FILTER-on-multiple-tables/m-p/304137 of Zubair.  My query is like below. Basically, the most of the data is coming from the `Append1` table while the users' information is coming from the `All_HR_Hierarchy` table. The `ASSIGNED_USER` column in `Append1` is found in the `HISL_ID` column of the `All_HR_Hierarchy` table. But when I run this query, I get an error like `A single value for column 'HISL_ID' in table 'All_HR_Hierarchy' cannot be determined`. Per the linked page, a single value should be found? So basically, per row of the output, as I there should be a `USERNAME` and a `HISL_ID` value?

```
SELECTCOLUMNS(        
   FILTER ('Append1',          
    ( [ASSIGNED_USER] =  \"68167\" || [ASSIGNED_USER] =  \"727675\"  )
    &&  CALCULATE ( ( 'All_HR_Hierarchy'[HISL_ID]  =   68167 ||   'All_HR_Hierarchy'[HISL_ID]  =   727675))   
   ), 
    \"USERNAME\", 'Append1'[ASSIGNED_USER],
   \"HISL_ID\", 'All_HR_Hierarchy'[HISL_ID] 
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on wrong track to begin with. As Zubair's linked article said, the Filter function would only take any matching values from the `Append1` table; the Filter statement would never have any values actually from the `All_HR_Heirarchy` table and hence the error.

So here is how I ended up doing it as in the code below. Do note that in the code below I am only getting values from the `Append1` table but  I did similar logic in another/separate Pipeline item (these are Databricks work in Azure Synapse Analytics) for the `All_HR_Heirarchy` table items. I am planning to combine the outputs from the two Pipeline items via a Python script; not ideal but will get the job done.

```
SELECTCOLUMNS(
CALCULATETABLE(
  'Append1' , 
   FILTER ('Append1', 
   [ASSIGNED_USER] =  \"68167\" || [ASSIGNED_USER] =  \"727675\"  ) 
),
   \"REF_NUM\", 'Append1'[REF_NUM],
   \"USERNAME\", 'Append1'[ASSIGNED_USER],
   \"RISK\", 'Append1'[RISK]
) _
```